# Remove deselected checkbox value from Array using Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, checkbox

This is simple one but i still somehow couldn't get it to work.

I have default value checked, checkbox. So when edit, of course the default value is chosen, but later I want to remove the default value and choose another value. Here it is

```
array1=[] //empty
```

After I check a checkbox, it will inserted to this array

```
array1=["sun"]
```

If I select 3 values  (`array1["sun","stars","moon"]`)
but I deselect the first selection (the default selection), it will be still in the array. (`array1["sun","stars","moon"]`) but I the expected result is this:

```
array1["stars","moon"]
```

No more first selection. So how to remove deselected value from array using Angular/Javascript?

I have tried use `splice`, `remove` and `set`

Answer (score 2):

Same thing developed and used in project :

Template side :

```
<label *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies" #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [value]="hobby" 
    (change)="populateMyHobbies(hobby,$event.target.checked)" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby}}</span>
</label>
```

Component Side :

```
selectedHobbies = [];

populateMyHobbies(value , status:boolean)
{
    if(this.selectedHobbies.indexOf(value) === -1 && status)
    {
        this.selectedHobbies.push(value);
    }
    else if(!status)
    {
        let index = this.selectedHobbies.indexOf(value);
        this.selectedHobbies.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Here `selectedHobbies` will give you what you want.

Have to change just name as per your app.

Comment: tq vivek, but my code still adding the default value. but it is ok, you code helped me too. let  me try again

Comment: Thanks ,  @user3431310

Answer (score 1):

i used it once in my project. change the code according to your need. logic is same.

**html part**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{category._id}}" (change)="pushpopcategory(category._id)" id="{{category._id}}">
```

**component code**

```
pushpopcategory(value) {
        if ((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(value)).checked) {
            this.categoryAdd.push(value);
        } else {
            let indexx = this.categoryAdd.indexOf(value);
            this.categoryAdd.splice(indexx, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your if-else gives me goosebumps. Also,  please remove spaces in `<>` to avoid confusion for potential readers

Comment: @Dummy my friend you can change format. i will accept you edit.

Comment: hi @AmitSuhag i did have this code , i have tried , it is not working, coz this type of code will only work when the user click and unclick. but what about if the default value is there and pushed inside array. so evrytime i click submit it will go to this default value n pushed and later if user dont want , it supposed to removed(coz we used spliced there), but unfortunately it is not removed....

Comment: @user3231310 you have not mention anything in question. this code is for adding and removing into array. try console.log in your code it may help to detect issue. add plnkr of your code if possible